# How to create a bidirectional encrypted stream on top of an underlying .NET Stream?

Tags: .net, security, cryptography

I have a Stream which transmits and receives data over an insecure channel. I have a pre-shared secret that both endpoints of the channel already have (say, a passphrase).

I'd like to construct a new stream using the secret and the original insecure stream. The two issues I came across are:

- CryptoStream is one-way: read-only or write-only. I can create *two* streams (a reading and a writing stream) on top of my original Stream, but this is unacceptable. Do I have to write a wrapper stream to get what I want? (namely, a single read/write stream)
- CryptoStream is said to work in blocks, and may not write anything to the underlying stream until the block is complete. Ideally I'd like to write any amount of data and have it be sent to the underlying stream (encrypted) immediately.

Is there an easy way of achieving this? I know of SslStream, but it's tailored towards private/public keys and certificates, rather than pre-shared secrets.

Comment: Why is creating two streams unacceptable? In a circumstance like this, I'd usually want to set different crypto keys for the two "sessions" that are happening here (e.g. use `HASH(passphrase + '||' + sender name)` as the key)

Comment: @Damien because I have further streams layered on top of this one, and I don't want to duplicate all of them.

Comment: if you need the semantics of a single stream object that supports Read and Write (but, presumably not seek), but defers those operations to a "ReadStream" or "WriteStream" that have been passed to it in it's construction, that should only take a page of code or so to write. So you could use the Crypto classes to add the encryption on both sides of the channel, and then use this other class to present it as a single stream to higher layers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I doubt you will come back and accept an answers two years later, however I just did what you are asking about, and I think it is a fairly common problem so I am posting this for the benefit of others that may come across this question.

I incorporated GregS' information into my implementation. For your specific purpose, you would make the Initialize method your constructor, strip out the net & diffie-hellman code, and assign your pre-shared key to the Aes object (instead of the generated key).

Please note that I am using AES256 despite that it has been compromised to being of similar strength to AES128 (if your keys are related because of bad implementation, which mine are not to my knowledge). If you do not trust NIST to know if the NSA is messing with their specs, then do NOT use AES.

Also, this is a starting point! I am working through the commonly encountered problem of sending encrypted data over a NetworkStream in .NET!

In a hundred twelve lines or less, without further ado:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

namespace FullDuplexCrypto
{
    class CryptoNetworkStream : Stream
    {
        public CryptoNetworkStream(IPAddress address, int port)
        {
            Socket socket = new Socket(SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            socket.Connect(address, port);
            //socket.NoDelay = true;
            Initialize(new NetworkStream(socket, true));
        }

        public CryptoNetworkStream(Socket socket)
        {
            Initialize(new NetworkStream(socket, true));
        }

        private void Initialize(Stream stream)
        {
            underlyer = stream;

            using(ECDiffieHellmanCng dh = new ECDiffieHellmanCng())
            {
                dh.KeyDerivationFunction = ECDiffieHellmanKeyDerivationFunction.Hash;
                dh.HashAlgorithm = CngAlgorithm.Sha256;
                byte[] buffer = dh.PublicKey.ToByteArray();
                underlyer.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                underlyer.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

                using(Aes aes = Aes.Create())
                {
                    aes.KeySize = 256;
                    aes.Key = dh.DeriveKeyMaterial(CngKey.Import(buffer, CngKeyBlobFormat.EccPublicBlob));
                    aes.FeedbackSize = 8;
                    aes.Mode = CipherMode.CFB;

                    underlyer.Write(aes.IV, 0, aes.IV.Length);
                    encrypter = new CryptoStream(underlyer, aes.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write);

                    underlyer.Read(aes.IV, 0, aes.IV.Length);
                    decrypter = new CryptoStream(underlyer, aes.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Read);
                }
            }
        }

        private Stream underlyer;
        private Stream encrypter;
        private Stream decrypter;

        public override bool CanRead { get { return decrypter.CanRead; } }
        public override bool CanWrite { get { return encrypter.CanWrite; } }
        public override bool CanSeek { get { return underlyer.CanSeek; } }
        public override long Length { get { return underlyer.Length; } }
        public override long Position { get { return underlyer.Position; } set { underlyer.Position = value; } }

        public override void Flush()
        {
            encrypter.Flush();
        }

        public override int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
        {
            return decrypter.Read(buffer, offset, count);
        }

        public override void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
        {
            encrypter.Write(buffer, offset, count);
        }

        public override long Seek(long offset, SeekOrigin origin)
        {
            return underlyer.Seek(offset, origin);
        }

        public override void SetLength(long value)
        {
            underlyer.SetLength(value);
        }

        private bool isDisposed = false;

        protected override void Dispose(bool isDisposing)
        {
            if(!isDisposed)
            {
                if(isDisposing)
                {
                    // Release managed resources.
                    encrypter.Dispose();
                    decrypter.Dispose();
                    underlyer.Dispose();

                }
                // Release unmanaged resources.

                isDisposed = true;
            }
            base.Dispose(isDisposing);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The `~CryptoNetworkStream()` and `.Dispose()` is not good. You can not guarantee that the 3 inner streams will not have been finialized yet when the finalizer for your class is is run (The GC Finalizer works as a heap not a queue). You should changed to the standard dispose pattern and only call `.Dispose()` on the 3 inner streams if it is explicitly called on the outer stream.

Comment: Sure... updated to reflect MS' dispose pattern. Normally I would treat streams as unmanaged resources, but you suggested only disposing them if it is done explicitly.

Comment: It still was not right, because your class inherits from the abstract base class `Stream` and because that class implements the dispose pattern already, neither `Dispose()` nor `~CryptoNetworkStream()` should not be used in your class (you also need to explicitly override `void Dispoese(bool)` and call the base class's version of it at the end). I have made the corrections.

Comment: When I made the first comment I did not realize you where inheriting from `Stream` ignore my previous ignorance :(

Comment: No worries. I edited it to reflect its current state on my local machine and to highlight the dispose pattern a bit more. Feel free to check that I have things straight now.

Comment: Your doubts were unfounded :) Looks fine to me.

Comment: Well would you look at that... Thanks. I'm glad to be proven wrong. In retrospect I probably should have realized as much given your involvement in SO.

Comment: @watkinsj will this work on a file and be able to seek and read from any part of the file?  Basically i am trying to write an encrypted file and be able to read it from any starting position in the file. Just noticed the Socket gets wrapped in a NetworkStream so seaking etc is disabled so wont work in my use case.

Comment: This is specifically for wrapping a network socket, and it doesn't actually work perfectly, yet. I haven't touched it in months. This may provide inspiration for me to. To answer your question - no. In fact, what you are asking to do is a bad idea. You should load your decrypted file into memory, and then encrypt it back to disc. That's if you are not looking for end to end encryption. A great deal of benefit is provided by the IV, which makes (when enabled) seeking a CryptoStream impossible.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to correctly transmit and read IV's, but you can use a block cipher, for example AES, in CFB mode with a feedback size of 8 bits to eliminate the "blocky" limitation. I think you'll have to write your own crypto stream to get the bidirectional behavior you want.

On the encrypt side of the stream generate a random IV and transmit it first. On the decrypt side read the IV bytes first from the stream, then initialize the cipher transform with it and then pass the remaining bytes read from the stream through the crypto transform.

If you are willing to use the [Bouncycastle C# library](http://www.bouncycastle.org/csharp/) you can get the benefits of all the security engineering and analysis that went into TLS/SSL using pre-shared keys by using the `SrpTlsClient` class. This class implements the [SRP ciphersuites](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5054) in TLS.

EDIT:

Nevermind about SRP TLS, the Bouncycastle library only has the client side of the protocol. Too bad.